# Check if value exists in database or not in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have wishlist system where i save `user_id` and `product_id` and i want to check before save into wishlist table to see if user already saved this product in there or not.

I found some question and articles about this but all of them only validate 1 value and not both, what I need is to check `auth::user()->id` and `product->id` both before saving.

here is my store method:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
      //Validating title and body field
      $this->validate($request, array(
          'user_id'=>'required',
          'product_id' =>'required',
        ));

      $wishlist = new Wishlist;

      $wishlist->user_id = $request->user_id;
      $wishlist->product_id = $request->product_id;


      $wishlist->save();

      return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message',
          'Item, '. $wishlist->product->title.' Added to your wishlist.');
    }
```

this is my form:

```
<form action="{{route('wishlist.store')}}" method="post">
                                    {{csrf_field()}}
                                    <input type="text" name="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}" hidden>
                                    <input type="text" name="product_id" value="{{$pdts->id}}" hidden>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                                        <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                                    </button>
                                  </form>
```

thanks.

Comment: `$this->validate`, can't you add [`exists`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-exists)?

Comment: @BagusTesa if i add exist then even if user have 1 wishlist cant add second one because his id is there already, what i need is comparing user_id and product_id if == with new one then show error if not add it as new one.

Comment: so i need to check both id's

Comment: Laravel doesn't provide validation like this out of the box. You'll need to create a custom validation rule - check the docs for more info https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: You could use `exists` if you wanted to make sure that given pair of user_id/product_id exists in the database. Unfortunately, there is no built_in rule like `not_exists`

Comment: alternatively, go to db validation, let `user_id` and `product_id` be `UNIQUE INDEX` and whenever you can't insert means that user already have that. application side validation does not guarantee you won't have duplicates.

Comment: You could also use [`firstOrCreate()` or `updateOrCreate()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models) and forget about validating the uniqueness of the composite key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the isset function to check whether the property is set or not

```
public function store (Request $request)
{

          // backend validator goes code here
          $status=Wishlist::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
                                           ->where('product_id',$request->product_id)
                                           ->first();

           if(isset($status->user_id) and      isset($request->product_id))
           {
                  //Return to already added page
           }
          else
          {
                  //Return to successfully added page
          }
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`firstOrCreate()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models) and forget about validating the composite key.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'user_id'    => 'required',
        'product_id' => 'required'
    ]);

    $wishlist = Wishlist::firstOrCreate($data);

    return redirect()
        ->back()
        ->with('flash_message', 'Item, ' . $wishlist->product->title . ' added to your wishlist.');
}
```

The `firstOrCreate()` method will try to find a record from your wishlists table with the given data and, in case it didn't find any, it will create a new one and return it.

In other words, if it can't find a record with the given `user_id` and `product_id` values, it will create a new one.

Or you could register a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules) like you have been already suggested.

Answer (score 2):

'email' => "required|email|exists:users,email,email,$request->email",

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for performing this, is to make a new rule.

You can run this command: `php artisan make:rule NameOfRule`

then write your logic through NameOfRule class's passed method  the file will be located under 'App\Rules' folder.

For example :

```
   public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return User::where(' add your wheres if needed')->exist();
    }
```

After this you can call your self rule as new instance.
For example :

```
$request->validate(['name'=>[new NameOfRule]]);
```